# How to create time group using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with three inputs with date and time. Here I collected my data not in pattern time. Here what I want first is put my start time as 0 and convert other time into minutes. 
my code is:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv',"," )
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

lastday = data.loc[0, 'date']
def convert_time(x):
  global lastday
  if x.date() == lastday.date():
    tm = x - lastday
    return tm.total_seconds()/60
else:
    lastday = x
    return 0

 data['time'] = data['date'].apply(convert_time)
```

Then I got the results:

[image]

But what I expected is :
I want to set the time for every one minute from starting time 0 , then if column has no value at that time then put the 0 values. If values are append then put the value with time column in minutes.

If new day then put again start time as 0 then start the value in minutes .

This is like time group with one minute , data.

```html
   Date        time in min       X1          X2       X3
   10/3/2018     1               63          0        0
             2
             3
             4         if no values then put 0 values into that
             5                 column till the values available 
             6        Then put it that column values
             7
             8
             9
             10
             11
             12
             13
  10/4/2018  0            120      30       60
             1             0       0        0
```

My csv file:

[image: My csv file]

link for my csv:

[My csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

After new code my time is displaying :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has functions for this; `resample` from a datetime index. You have to give an aggregation feature in case your data has multiple values within 1 minute. Below example will sum these values, it is easy to change this.

Please correct me if this is not what you want.

**Code**

```
# Read CSV
csv_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=1512153575'
data = pd.read_csv(csv_url)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

# Resample to 1 minute (T is minute)
df = data.set_index('date') \
    .resample('1T') \
    .sum() \
    .fillna(0)

# Optional ugly one-liner to start index at 0, and 1 row per minute, restart at day start
df.index = ((df.index - pd.to_datetime(df.index.date)).total_seconds() / 60).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
df.head()

                    x1  x2  x3  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7
date                        
2018-03-10 06:15:00 63  0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
2018-03-10 06:16:00 0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
2018-03-10 06:17:00 0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
2018-03-10 06:18:00 0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
2018-03-10 06:19:00 0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
```

**Output 2**
With ugly-ass one-liner

```
    x1  x2  x3  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7
date                        
0   63  0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
2   0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
3   0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
4   0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
5   0   0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I have one question, when the new day is coming my start time should be again 0 and then count minute from that time. Is this code running like this? when I apply your code I can see that your code is counting whole days minutes together.

Comment: @ Laurens Koppenol  When I put your new code then time value displayed like this . I posted the image of time. It is not starting from 0 . It is starting 375

Answer (score 0):

You may creat a dataframe `df2` contain the column `time` and `minutes of day`, and then use

```
csv_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=1512153575'
data = pd.read_csv(csv_url)    
df = pd.merge(data,df2,how='outer',on='time')
df = df.fillna(0)
```

`df2` is like the pic, you can create it by script or excel

[image]

Comment: I can't understand your code. Can you please explain your code? Here what is this df1 , df2

Comment: Ya I tried your method earlier.. But it is hard typing and create a new excel. To skip that ,I am searching a code for this.

Comment: if you not use the time string column, use you code in questions, then only need create a dataframe contain all  number in range(60*24).